# Result error when using 'if' statement, and '<<', '>>' operators to compare 3 integers

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is a half-done code, which I am stuck with when the input is: i1 = 3, i2 = 5, i3 = 7.

```
#include < iostream >
#include < string >
#include < vector >
#include < algorithm >
#include < cmath >
using namespace std;

//Comparing Integers

int main()
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;

    cout << "Enter 3 integers: ";
    cin >> i1 >> i2 >> i3;


    int diff_3_1 = i3 - i1;
    int diff_3_2 = i3 - i2;

    if (diff_3_1 >> diff_3_2){
        cout << i1 << " is smaller than " << i2 << '\n';
    }

    if (diff_3_1 << diff_3_2){
        cout << i2 << " is smaller than " << i1 << '\n';
    }


}
```

Both output from the two 'if' operators are printed out. I can't find the error. I know that by replacing the second operator with 'else if' would work. However, I would like to know my error in this case.

Results:

i1 = 3, i2 = 5, i3 = 7

diff_3_1 = 4, diff_3_2 = 2

1st statement:
diff_3_1 >> diff_3_2,(which is true)

hence, "3 is smaller than 5" is printed.

but,

2nd statement:
diff_3_1 << diff_3_2, (which is false)

prints out, "5 is smaller than 3".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a beginners' tutorial site.

Comment: You just picked the wrong operators, `==` for equality doesn't mean `<<` for less-than. BTW: Instead of telling people what to enter as input, just hard-code the values that cause the unexpected behaviour into the code. Also, if both if-clauses behave unexpected and they are not fundamentally different, reduce your code to just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

`>>` isn't a comparison, it's a bit shift. Just **`>`** is greater than.